# Python, Бот ВК, вопрос про асинхронность

Tags: python, вконтакте, асинхронность

Как можно реализовать асинхронную обработку запросов пользователей, пример:

Пользователь **A** отправляет сообщение, пока его сообщение обрабатывалось в функции handler(), написал ещё один пользователь **B**, бот должен тоже обработать полученное сообщение в функции handler(), не ожидая окончания обработки для пользователя **A**.

Где можно найти примеры таких реализаций? Как вообще и с помощью чего можно реализовать подобное? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Как выглядит код сейчас:

```
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(self.vk_g_session, group_id=self.GROUP_ID)
        while True:
             for event in longpoll.listen():
                   func(event)
```

Comment: Посмотрите модуль `multiprocessing`.